# Group mongodb documents into two groups based on a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoid

I have collection `task`, which has a couple thousand documents. Each document has a `success` field with either `true` or `false` as a value. Here is an example document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bd31f64c3a106f0392a7213"),
    "current_user_id" : 9,
    "company_id" : 239,
    "project_id" : 2,
    "user_action" : "create_project",
    "success" : true,
    "uuid" : "cf0cb41c-9c3b-4f2f-b82b-3516d2c18fc2",
    "created_at" : "2018-10-26 17:06:28.479871"
}
```

I would like to get the documents grouped into two: those that have `success: true` in one array, and those that have `success: false` in another.

I tried to make two queries with filters `success:true` for the first one and `success:false` for the other:

```
db.getCollection('tasks').find({ 'company_id': 239,
                'success': true
               })
```

Comment: You mean `"success": true ` instead of `success: true`, and so on?

Comment: hey @sawa my question would be, how would I group and return the documents separated into two arrays,  instead of making two queries to get those that have `"success": false` and those that have `"success": true`, how would I get this in one query. Hope this clarifies the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get data with few way

`First way`

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            "true": [
                {
                    $match: {
                        "success" : true
                    }
                }   
            ],
            "false": [
                {
                    $match: {
                        "success" : false
                    }
                }   
            ]
        }
    }    
])
```

`Second way`

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$success",
            result: {
                $push: {
                   "current_user_id" : 1,
                    "company_id" : 1,
                    "project_id" : 1,
                    "user_action" : 1,
                    "uuid" : 1,
                    "created_at" : 1
                }
            }

        }
    }    
])
```

if you have any question let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query :

```
db.col.aggregate([{ $group: { _id:"$success","data" : {"$push" : "$$ROOT"}}}])
```